# Connector identification - Unknown connector

Tags: identification, connector

A friend has had a thermostat failure, and a cable is on (very long) backorder. It's getting cold up here in New England, so he asked if I can identify the connector type so that he might get a temporary replacement.

Well, I can't. It's not something I recognize, although it stirs very faint memories.

Can anybody help?

[image]

Comment: It's a standard pluggable terminal block. Without dimensions (e.g. pitch), further details can't be given.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - Thanks for the response. I've pinged my friend for a pitch measurement. In the meantime, is there a manufacturer I could take a look at?

Comment: Phoenix Contact makes connectors like that.

Comment: what's wrong with the cable?

Comment: Seriously, it's a super common terminal block, they are literally everywhere. Just measure the pitch. Spontaneously it looks like 3,5mm but it's hard to tell from a picture.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - I heard from my friend, and a connector I found from Phoenix seems to work. Had to go to Mouser, since Digikey was out of stock, but he got it today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If the pitch is 5 mm: https://www.digikey.com/short/f8dw0vm1 (various brands, including Phoenix Contact COMBICON MSTBVA 1755590)

If the pitch is 5.08 mm: https://www.digikey.com/short/mbmmpwh3 (various brands, including Molex Eurostyle ESE 39535 0395355011).